# Using own user repository/ database table for IdentitiyServer3 to authenticate against

Tags: single-sign-on, thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture-ident-model, thinktecture, identityserver3

Can you please help me with some insight on using my own User repository/ database table for Identity server (IdentityServer3) to authenticate against? 
I know other people have done it, but can’t seem to figure out how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a user service.  The docs and samples have very good coverage of that.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/advanced/userService.html